# Why does "if [ 0 ]" execute the "then" statement in bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

[This guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) says:

```
 An if/then construct tests whether the exit status of a list of commands is 0
```

If I execute `0` in the bash, it says:

```
0: command not found
```

So its exit status is not 0, and `[ 0 ]` should return a non-zero value exit status too. But it returns 0 exit status actually, and `if [ 0 ]` executes the `then` statement, not the `else` statement.
Can anyone explain it?

Comment: `if[0]` will not even be recognized as an `if`; it will try to find a command called `if[0]`, typically fail, and tell you `if[0]: command not found`. Assuming you're getting `0: command not found`, are you sure there aren't *spaces* you're neglecting to include, in your statement of the problem here? Please note that `if[0]`, `if [0]`, and `if [ 0 ]` are all quite different.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan Oh, so ti is. Sorry for my typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[` isn't part of the `if` statement, it is a command that evaluates expressions. The `[ 0 ]` returns true because the form `[ Expression ]` always evaluates to 0. If you try `if [ 1 -eq 2 ]` the `then` statement will not run.

Check the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/test.1posix.html) for more info.

Comment: Should also be noted for the beginners that `-eq` flag is arithmetic comparison, while `=` is string (i.e. textual comparison). Compare  `[ 01 -eq 1  ]  && echo "YES"` and `[ 01 = 1  ]  && echo "YES"`. The later won't output `YES`, because `01` and `1` are different strings of text, while `-eq` treats these as numbers.